# Corda State Events : Do events have an order?

Tags: events, blockchain, corda

A network consist of 3 nodes, where 1 node is read-only and participates in every transaction. Request can start from either of the nodes which in turn creates a request state. It is received and processed by other node to create a new response state. Both only issue new states and do not consume the state. Both these state events are received by the read-only node. Would the State events received by the read-only corda node have an order or would it be processed in any order ?

For eg can we say that the request originator state event would be received/processed first and then the other node ? or can it be possible under high load that the other node request gets received/processed by the read-only node first and then the originators event is received.

My experience with corda is very minimal and need to understand

> how events are received by the parties when one party acts as
>   read-only and all remaining parties only issue new states.

Comment: It depends on how the transactions is made.you are saying request state is issued and then response , ideally, order will remain same if you are dealing this in separate transaction. Anyways , question is too broad .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the order of the receiving messages is not guaranteed. A node will process messages in the order it receives them. But it's not guaranteed that the received messages are sequential.

If Node A is receiving messages from Node B and Node C, and Node B produces a message before node C. There is no guarantee that the message from Node B is processed first. The one which reaches Node A first gets processed first. The delay could be because of multiple reasons like network latency, etc.